# Modifying plist in Python

Tags: python, plist

With plistlib I can serialize a dictionary / list structure into a plist. This works ok and I can also read it back with the same library.

The problem is that dictionaries are of type "_internalDict" and I don't seem to be able to change them. For exampl, for example:

```
d = plistlib.readPlist('someplist.plist')
v = d['value'] # v is an _internalDict
v['val'] = 'new val' # works
del v # doesn't work
v = {'someotherkey': 'someothervalue'} # doesn't work either
```

The plist doesn't seem to change. Help?

Comment: `del v` deletes the whole dictionary, and `v = {...}` creates a new dictionary. Is that what you want, or are you trying to delete keys from the dict? The `_InternalDict` is just a `dict` subclass that leaves normal `dict` operations in place.

Comment: yes, this is what i want

Comment: Then you do not have a problem, in my view; are you getting errors when you delete the whole dictionary, or when you replace it with a new one altogether? `plistlib` can deal with regular dicts just fine, btw.

Comment: i'm not getting any error, i delete the reference and in the following line it's still there. i replace it all together and it's still the old one :/

Comment: Yeah, it clicked what you are trying to do and where your misunderstanding lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to delete the key from the `d` dict:

```
del d['value']
```

By setting `v = d['value']` you are only creating a new variable that points to the same value as `d['value']`, but deleting `v` will not remove the dict from the parent structure.

To replace the dict altogether, you again need to manipulate the parent dict:

```
d['value'] = { 'foo': 'bar' }
```

If you execute `v = { ... }` what you are doing is assigning a reference to a new `dict` value to the variable `v`, replacing the reference to the `d['value']` `dict`; you are not manipulating the original value in the `d` dict.

`plistlib._InternalDict` is just a subclass of `dict` that gives warnings for attribute access, which is now deprecated; otherwise it acts just like a regular `dict` type.